# Is there a relationship between the standard error of a fixed effect and the standard deviation of a random effect?

Tags: r, mixed-model, standard-error

```
library(lme4)
data("sleepstudy")

head(sleepstudy)

m1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ 1 + (1|Subject), data=sleepstudy)
summary(m1)
```

In the above example we get a measure of mean/intercept as a fixed effect = 298.51 which is like the average subject Reaction time. We also fit a random effect of subject and get a SD on this of 37.12. So the model of the distribution is Gaussian with a mean of 298.51 and SD of 37.12.

However, what is the relationship between the uncertainty based on the random effect and the uncertainty around the mean represented by the standard error which equals 9.05?

In general, is the sampling distribution of the statistic related to the normal distribution that uses the fixed and random effects to define its parameters?

Comment: Good questsion ! (+1). Intuitively we might think that incorporating random effects will reduce the standard error of the fixed intercept, but that is not the case as we can see by running `lm(Reaction ~ 1, data=sleepstudy)`. On the other hand if we introduce a covariate as a fixed effect, we do see this: `lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1|Subject), data=sleepstudy)` vs `lm(Reaction ~ Days, data=sleepstudy)`. So I can't answer the question, hence this is only a comment, but I'll have a think about it later and maybe run some simulations.